# Freebsd setfacl

Tags: freebsd, acl, umask, setfacl

I want on a dir,a default mask of --- for others

on linux

```
setfacl -d -m  o:--- coldir/
```

works fine

On Freebsd 11.0,with ufs2

```
setfacl -d -m  other:--- coldir/
setfacl: other:---: Invalid argument

setfacl -m m::others:--- coldir/
setfacl: malformed ACL: invalid "tag" field
setfacl: m::others:---: Invalid argument
```

How to solve using setfacl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,syntax was a little different

```
 sudo setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::,mask::rwx coldir/
```

So new dir created are 770,perfect for collaborative dir.

Comment: Actually, _that_ syntax is the same across the tools, as long as you use a single `-` for the empty permissions.  It is the syntax that you used on Linux in your question that is the different one.